# Conversion failed when converting date from character string in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am facing an issue with running a stored procedure with a Date parameter. I have 2 parameters in a stored procedure which returns a result set from a table. In the table `name` is of type `nvarchar` and `dateclient` is a `date`.

The value of the parameters are coming from an user interface.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NAME_SEARCH] 
    @name nvarchar(255),
    @dateclient datetime
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @parsed_string nvarchar(max)

    EXEC parsing_coi_input @name, @parsed_string OUTPUT

    PRINT @parsed_string

    SET @name = @parsed_string

    DECLARE 
        @BaseQuery nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT Id, name, date_client
                                    FROM Client
                                    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Client, ame,'''+ @name + ''') as name_key ON ID = name_key.[KEY]'
   DECLARE 
        @OrderByQuery nvarchar(max) = ' ORDER BY name_key.RANK'
   DECLARE
        @OrderDesc nvarchar(max) =' DESC'

   BEGIN 
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       SET @BaseQuery = @BaseQuery + ' 
   INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Client, date_client,'''+ @dateclient  +''') AS 
   date_clientkey ON ID = date_clientkey.[KEY] WHERE date_client_matter_open >= '+ @dateclientmatter  
    +''
   SET @OrderByQuery = @OrderByQuery + ',date_client_key.RANK'

   END 

    DECLARE @fullQuery nvarchar(max)= @BaseQuery + @OrderByQuery + @OrderDesc
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @fullQuery
    END
```

I am executing:

```
EXEC [dbo].[NAME_SEARCH] 'MGeolo','2009-04-05'
```

But I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: What you *should* be getting is an error that you have too many arguments specified, as your sproc definition has only two parameters and you're passing 5. Double check that you're looking at the right thing. The rest is an SQL injection waiting to happen; you have to go dynamic here because `CONTAINSTABLE` does not support parameters, but do make sure to escape strings properly when you have to do something like this (replace single apostrophes with double). Last but not least always `PRINT` the result of dynamic SQL before execution so you can check what's happening.

Comment: Procedure dbo.NameSearch creates dynamic sql.  Can you provide the sql generated?  For example,  appears to be a custom proc called by dbo.NameSearch.  Normally the error you posted indicates that SQL Server is comparing your input against a  varchar column where values exist that cannot be converted to datetime.

Comment: `+ CAST(@dateclient AS nvarchar(20))  +` maybe? Although it's not clear if you actually want to *search* a column which is `datetime` I don't think that is possible

Comment: + CAST(@dateclient AS nvarchar(20))  +  I have tried this but didn't work out

Comment: **Warning**: your code is wide open to inject attacks. Never inject unsanitised strings in your SQL.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert , I have made the changes , there area only 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ' characters around your date when the SQL script is generated and a cast from datetime to varchar.

You should do like:

```
BEGIN 
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       SET @BaseQuery = @BaseQuery + ' 
   INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Client, date_client,'''+ cast(@dateclient as varchar(200))  +''') AS 
   date_clientkey ON ID = date_clientkey.[KEY] WHERE date_client_matter_open >= '''+ cast(@dateclientmatter as varchar(200)) +''''
   SET @OrderByQuery = @OrderByQuery + ',date_client_key.RANK'
```

It is probably a typo but the @dateclientmatter is undeclared because in the header you have only @dateclient.